# Porting C code which uses fork() to Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have written an application in C which I am porting to Android using the NDK. This application makes use of fork() to create child processes periodically to perform some tasks. These child processes communicate with the main process through pipes and then exit after their task is complete. The amount of data transferred through pipes can be hundreds of kilobytes.

I'm attempting to keep the parent process very lean in terms of memory and CPU consumption and also very stable, but the child processes can sometimes take up a significant amount of resources. It doesn't matter much if the child processes are sometimes killed by the system due to this. The parent process can gracefully handle these conditions.

For this use case, is it fine to keep the fork()s in the native code? Is there a better way of doing this through Android's framework?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message from goddess:

http://markmail.org/message/ruqp2t6gvhnhv654

So you better leave it off.  It could open a full can of worms with process management.  And there is nothing worse as misbehaving runaway native process  sucking processor cycles and battery juice.  Better solution would be several android abstractions like services  and broadcast receivers in same  process passing data around by means of static classes or firing intents

Comment: The article you reference seems to refer to forking the process and expecting to have two activities running afterwards, which is not possible on any platform that I'm aware of. The question here refers to forking a background process.

Comment: I *do* agree with the point that it is dangerous and that a runaway process is a bad thing. I don't know what happens if the GUI activity exits but fails to terminate its background process.

Comment: Yes, I intend to fork the process and execute some CPU and memory intensive tasks in the child processes which only execute C code in the background. They communicate with the main process using a pipe and when the main process dies, they can be terminated on receiving a SIGPIPE signal. The reason I want to do this is because I want the Android system to be free to kill the child process in case it uses too many resources, but the main process should not be killed. Is forking discouraged for this scenario as well?

Comment: If you want  your child process managed by android system, do not make it native process. fork() is clearly discouraged by android team for every purpose

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your kind responses. I'll come up with another way to get this done.