# Android ADB Tool, 'fork' doesn't work

Tags: android, c++, linux, adb, android-source

### Environment

- Android 5.0 @ Samsung Galaxy 5
- ADB @ Windows (x64)
- Native ADB Commandline tool

### Use-case

An application that forks and immediately exit

### Problem description

While fork returns a propper pid_t of the newly created process, no actual process is being created, ( *'adb -d shell ps | findstr shell'* shows no new process )

### Code snippet

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ScreenCapSvc", "\n");
pid_t pid = fork();
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ScreenCapSvc", "STARTED, pid = %d\n", pid);
if (0 != pid)
    return S_OK;// Exits the parent process
HRESULT hr;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ScreenCapSvc", "Initializing\n");
if (FAILED(hr = Initialize(pBaseAddress, wPort, uiMaxMessageSize)))
    return hr;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ScreenCapSvc", "Running modal loop\n");
hr = m_spIOCP->DoModal();
OnCleanup(hr);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ScreenCapSvc", "STOPPED, pid = %d\n", pid);
return S_OK;
```

### Logcat output

```
I/ScreenCapSvc(29062):
I/ScreenCapSvc(29062): STARTED, pid = 29064
```

### Additional info

If rather them immediately exiting the parent process I call eg. sleep(2) than the child process is properly forked, HOWEVER, While the parent process actually terminate, 'ADB -d shell' never exit ( stays hanging infinity ).

**Related link:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277361/android-adb-tool-c11-stdthread-usage 

What am I doing wrong? why does the process doesn't fork?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471552/porting-c-code-which-uses-fork-to-android

Comment: Is there a way to start an ADB command line tool in the background, thus, use ADB to start the tool and immediately return after the tool was started ( in the background ) ?

Comment: I don't know if it applies to Android, but when I did this sort of thing ages ago in "normal" unix, I had to call `setpgrp()` in the child to create a separate process group so the child wouldn't get killed when the parent died.